# Showing that the $(n-1)$-th derivative of $f' + \alpha f$ is zero at, at least, one point in the domain of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function in $\mathscr{C}^n(I)$ such that $f$ equals $0$ at $n+1$ distinct points in $I$. ($I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{C}^n(I)$ denotes that the $n$-th derivative of $f$ is continuous).

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that the $(n-1)$-th derivative of $f'+\alpha f$ is zero at, at least, one point in $I$.

**Attempt**

My guess is that I would have to use Darboux's theorem to get a value such that $f'+\alpha f  = 0$, but I am unsure how to utilize it.

The $(n-1)$-th derivative of $f'+\alpha f$ is $f^{(n)} + \alpha f^{(n-1)}$. We showed that there exists $a<b<c$ in $I$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(a) = f^{(n-1)}(c) = 0$ and $f^{(n)}(b) = 0$. Assume $f^{(n-1)}(b) \neq 0$ (otherwise we're done). Without loss of generality assume it is greater than 0. Then there exists $y\in(a,b)$ such that

$$
f^{(n)}(y) = \frac{f^{(n-1)}(b)}{b-a}
$$

Therefore for any $\beta\in\left(0, \frac{f^{(n-1)}(b)}{b-a}\right)$, there exists $z\in (y,b)$ such that $f^{n}(z) = \beta$.

But by the continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$, we similarly get that for any $\gamma\in\left(0,f^{(n-1)}(b)\right)$, there exists $j\in(a,b)$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(j) = \gamma$.

**Question**

Not really sure what to do after this. --Also my professor said I have to use ODEs but I do not know how that relates to this question (I have also never done any ODE-related thing before so if it indeed requires ODEs I would appreciate it if you explained why this is related to ODEs)-- (edit: I misunderstood the professor he just said ODEs will give you a hint as to what function will be helpful), since the solution to $f'+\alpha f = 0$ is global, but in this question we only need one point.

Comment: Look at the function $g(x)=e^{\alpha x}f(x)$, which vanishes at $n+1$ different points in $I$. By Rolle's theorem its derivative will vanish at at least $n$ different points that are between the $n+1$ at which $g$ vanishes. Note that $g'(x)=e^{\alpha x}(f'(x)+\alpha f(x))$. Since $e^{\alpha x}$ never vanishes then $f'+\alpha f$ vanishes at at least $n$ different points in $I$. After that continue using Rolle with $f'+\alpha f$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I figured out what to do the moment you suggested that function, haha